# Does Facebook’s 20% rule apply to sharing images on posts?

Tags: text, images, layout

I'm the social media designer for the company I work at, and most of our images are just used for posts. I've been asked to follow the 20% rule and have even been asked once or twice to make the text smaller.

Is this a rule I should be following if the images aren't ads? I've even used the text overlay tool to see what Facebook thinks of the images and received an *image text: low* score. Not the highest score, mind you, but the second best.

Comment: You should follow Facebook's [recommendations on their help page](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/980593475366490)

Comment: Not everyone is familiar with "Facebook's 20% rule".

Comment: @BillyKerr, that page refers to ads. I'm wondering if this same thing applies to just normal sharing images on posts.

Comment: @Scott, Facebook requires text to take up less than 20% of an ad image. They used to rule out all ad images that did not meet this criteria, but last year they changed it so that they score your image based on the text amount, then let you know how severely it will lower your ad reachability. if the text is high then they won't allow the image to be used.

Comment: There is no mention in the help pages of ordinary image posts on a page. However if it's an ordinary image post advertising something for a business, then it would make sense to apply the same recommendations because cramming too much text into an image is a bad idea anyway.